# Regex for number with 9 digits before the decimal and 1 to 3 digits after the decimal

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm stuck with trying to do a regular expression that allows 9 digits before the decimal place, and 1 to 3 digits if a decimal is used.

```
Eg:
123456789 //Valid
1234567890 //Invalid
123456789. //Invalid
123456789.0 //Valid
123456789.00 //Valid
123456789.000 //Valid
123456789.0000 //Invalid
Negative number are ok too
```

I was trying:

```
<?php

function numbers($val){
    return preg_match('/^[0-9]{1,9}([.]{0,1}([0-9]{1,3}))$/i',$val);
}

$n = '1234567899';

if(numbers($n)) {
    echo 'Valid Number';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid Number';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be making the decimal component optional:

```
^-?[0-9]{1,9}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3})?$
```

Your updated PHP function:

```
function numbers($val){
    return preg_match('/^-?[0-9]{1,9}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3})?$/i', $val);
}
```

Here is a demo of the regex pattern:

### Demo